# About JQuery conditional statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

if press the button, id #footer gets padding-top as much as class .box's outerHeight. When I press the button again, #footer's padding-top must be "0". but now #footer's padding-top doesn't change.

I tried many codes that ("padding-top",null), ("padding-top",0),  $("button").toggle(function(){}); etc..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var boxHeight = $(".box").stop().fadeToggle(10).outerHeight();
    $("#footer").css("padding-top", boxHeight);
  });
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul,
ol {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

button {
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img,
button,
input {
  border: 0;
}

html {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans KR', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}


/* layout */

.layout {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.layout:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}


/* footer */

#footer {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-top: 1px solid #0067ac;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  color: #6f6f6f;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}

#footer .layout {
  position: static;
  padding: 50px 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

#footer .wrap-btn {
  float: right;
}

#footer .wrap-btn button {
  position: relative;
  width: 121px;
  height: 38px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#footer .wrap-btn button:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 7px;
  width: 11px;
  height: 6px;
  background: url(../img/ir-common.png) no-repeat -115px -146px;
  content: "";
}

#footer .wrap-btn button,
#btn-top {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #0067ac;
  color: #6f6f6f;
}

#footer .wrap-btn .box {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0067ac;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

#footer .wrap-btn .box ul {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#footer .wrap-btn .box ul:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}

#footer .wrap-btn .box ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#footer .wrap-btn .box ul li a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer id="footer">
  <div class="layout">
    <div class="wrap-btn">
      <button type="button">button</button>
      <div class="box">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">contents</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">contents</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">contents</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">contents</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">contents</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">contents</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">contents</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">contents</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">contents</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">contents</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">contents</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">contents</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">contents</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: The problem is that `outerHeight` doesn't change when toggled. Not sure what jQuery does exactly when hiding the element, but even the computed style for `height` doesn't change. I recommend to stay away from jQuery and do this stuff by yourself, so you know for sure what it does.

Comment: connexo/thanks for your help very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the `.box` is visible, and if not set the `padding-top` to `0`;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var v = $(".box").is(":visible");
    var boxHeight = $(".box").stop().fadeToggle(10).outerHeight();
    $("#footer").css("padding-top", v == false ? boxHeight : 0);
  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var v = $(".box").is(":visible");
    var boxHeight = $(".box").stop().fadeToggle(10).outerHeight();
    $("#footer").css("padding-top", v == false ? boxHeight : 0);
  });
});
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul,
ol {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

button {
  background: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img,
button,
input {
  border: 0;
}

html {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans KR', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}


/* layout */

.layout {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.layout:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}


/* footer */

#footer {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-top: 1px solid #0067ac;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  color: #6f6f6f;
  letter-spacing: 0;
}

#footer .layout {
  position: static;
  padding: 50px 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

#footer .wrap-btn {
  float: right;
}

#footer .wrap-btn button {
  position: relative;
  width: 121px;
  height: 38px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#footer .wrap-btn button:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 7px;
  width: 11px;
  height: 6px;
  background: url(../img/ir-common.png) no-repeat -115px -146px;
  content: "";
}

#footer .wrap-btn button,
#btn-top {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #0067ac;
  color: #6f6f6f;
}

#footer .wrap-btn .box {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #0067ac;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

#footer .wrap-btn .box ul {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#footer .wrap-btn .box ul:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}

#footer .wrap-btn .box ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#footer .wrap-btn .box ul li a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer id="footer">
  <div class="layout">
    <div class="wrap-btn">
      <button type="button">button</button>
      <div class="box">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">contents</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">contents</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">contents</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">contents</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">contents</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">contents</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">contents</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">contents</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">contents</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">contents</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">contents</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">contents</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">contents</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to track if your footer is open or not in order to achieve what you are trying to do.

Something like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  let footerOpen = false;
    $("button").click(function(){
        var boxHeight = $(".box").stop().fadeToggle(10).outerHeight();
        if(!footerOpen) {
          $("#footer").css("padding-top",boxHeight);
          footerOpen = true;
        } else {
          $("#footer").css("padding-top", 0); 
          footerOpen = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a working codepen: https://codepen.io/antonbks/pen/jONMNLB